# Is special relativity true?

Tags: special-relativity

Is the special theory of relativity true? http://www.npr.org/2014/03/20/291408248/einsteins-lost-theory-discovered-and-its-wrong

Comment: Yes. There is tons of experimental evidence for it. You could just have googled it.

Comment: Also, the article is talking about something else. Read through.

Comment: I agree with Hritik Narayan, you really should read through. I also didn't know about this failed attempt, who knows did Einstein fainted when he saw it, like Sheldon?

Comment: This question does not deserve down votes.

Comment: @mmesser314 I didn't down vote it, but I think people object to the link with no description. Especially writing a description would make the OP realize the answer to their own question, i.e. that it has nothing to do with SR. So it seems like an ad for the website, even though it probably isn't a marketing campaign. The down votes do tell other people that this isn't being encouraged to be emulated.

Comment: @Timaeus You have a point. I thought it was for the pseudo-science title of the link. If you don't follow the link, it sounds pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

The NPR article you posted discusses Einstein's attempt at solving [Lemaitre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Lema%C3%AEtre)'s theory of and [Hubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Hubble)'s discovery of the expanding universe (i.e., the [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang))

> It was trying to solve a big problem of the day. An astronomer named Edwin Hubble had just observed that everything in the universe is moving outward.
>
> ...
>
> Faced with evidence that the universe was growing, Einstein apparently wanted to figure out why it wasn't filling up with empty space. His proposed solution is in this newly discovered paper. As the universe expanded, he suggested, new matter showed up to fill the gaps. New stars and galaxies would just pop up, according to Einstein's model, so that even as the universe grew, it would look the same.

Turns out that Einstein had made a sign error (a common theme for him, apparently, as the article cites that "*[about] 20 percent of Einstein's papers contain various mistakes of various degrees*") in one of his equations that propagated through to the result. The paper discussed in the NPR article was *never* published and was authored about 20 years *after* the SR was published (the article claims that it was authored between prior to a 1931 paper, but had to be after Hubble's 1929 discovery).

So no, this doesn't disprove [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity), which has been tested [many times over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity), most notably with

- [The Michelson Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment)
- [The Kennedy-Thorndike experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy%E2%80%93Thorndike_experiment)
- [The Ives-Stilwell experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment)

among many others.

Comment: I can so relate to Einstein in that my work usually has many errors like wrong minuses or misplaced exponents, etc. Unlike Einstein, however, I haven't earned the right to make all the little mistakes I want like he has.

Answer (score 0):

The article you linked to is not about special relativity. There is no problem with special relativity.

This is a paper that Einstein started, but did not publish. As the article says, he did not publish it because he saw the mistake in it.

The article is disappointing, but not surprising for science reporting. The only reason it is newsworthy is that it is an opportunity to put words "Einstein", "lost theory", and "wrong" in the same headline. People will notice a headline like that. The article itself is better than some. It sounds like they got the facts right. Many reporters do not understand science well enough to do that.